# WinForms Target Screen Size

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm developing a VB.NET (though this issue also applies to C#) winforms application that will be targeting a device where the screen resolution is 1080x1920 in portrait. This means that when the application is running, the resolution is really 1920x1080.

This is causing a problem in development because I'm not using a monitor that I can physically rotate. When I try to set the size of the form to 1080,1920, Visual Studio is automatically resizing it to 1080,1100. Reading the notes for the Form.Size property, there is this blurb:

> The maximum value of this property is limited by the resolution of the
> screen on which the form runs. The value cannot be greater than 12
> pixels over each screen dimension (horizontal + 12 and vertical + 12).

But how can override this in my development environment since I know the form size in my production environment will meet this limitation? Is it possible?

Comment: Use a Panel as the actual container (MDI style) sized like that and let the Form scroll? Use a Monitor that can *physically rotate*?

Comment: @Jimi - Hurricane repairs mean that I cannot afford to purchase a better monitor, however adding a panel, setting the location to [0, 0], the size to [1080, 1920], adding the Form controls to the Panel, and then setting the Form's autoscroll to true while debugging did the trick. If you want to leave an answer I can upvote and accept it.